# Dynamically auto calculate total jquery with select and textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

hye, i am using jquery and laravel 7 for my project.

I use append row to add new row, and every appended row will be auto-calculated once it selects the service and fill in one of the textboxes. in the picture below, there are two textboxes, the first one is compulsory to fill in. the second one is optional, but when user input in the second textbox, the total must be calculated. otherwise, it will not be calculated if the user did not input the second textbox.

calculation: total = serviceName(value) * weight/size * opt

[service pls view this to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8eWh.png)

the problem for my codes, it only calculate the first row, i think because the next row is not unique so it doesn't auto calculate. I've tried to add index but it does not work as i am still new with jquery. also, i don't want the optional textbox to be compulsory fill in. i want it to be optional only. if i didn't fill in the optional textbox, the total is not appear

here is my create.blade.php + jquery inside ,

````
@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
@endsection

@section('content')
<form action="#" class="mt-3" method="POST" >
    @csrf
    <div class="col-8 col-md-10" >
        <div class="card" style="width: 550px;"><!--style="width: 700px;"-->
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title">Create Order</h3>
                <!--<h6 class="card-subtitle">To use add <code>is-valid</code> class to the input</h6>-->
               
                    <label class="form-control-label" >Order Date</label>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{  now("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")->toDateString() }}" readonly></br>
                    
                    <label class="form-control-label" >Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_search" name="custPhone" maxlength="12"> </br>

                    <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust_name" readonly placeholder="id"  ></br>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_id" id="cust_id" > </br>

                <h4 class="card-title ">Service</h4>
                                   
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-sm btn-success mr-3  mb-2 float-right" id="addserv"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Service</button>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="input-group adds mb-3" id="input-group"  >
                                    <select class="form-control col-8 mr-2" name="" id="service1" >
                                    @foreach ($services as $s)
                                    <option id="option" value="{{$s->servicePrice}}" data-index="{{$loop->index}}" >{{$s -> serviceName}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-3 mr-2" name="quantity"   id="weightsize0" data-index="0" placeholder="weight/size" >
                                   
                                     <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-3 mr-2" name="addonqty"  id="quantity0" data-index="0" placeholder="add-on" >
                                    <button type="button" class="minus btn btn-danger" id="remove"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>     
                    <label class="form-control-label" >Total</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" readonly  id="total"> </br>
        </div>
                
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-dark">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
<!-- Script -->

@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    // CSRF Token
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $( "#customer_search" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // Fetch data
          $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('Autocomplte.getAutocomplte')}}",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
               _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
               search: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
               response( data );
            }
            
          });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item);
            $('#customer_search').val(ui.item.value);
            $('#cust_name').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#cust_id').val(ui.item.id);
            
            return false;
        }
      });

      //test1
        //append line ver2
       
        var j = 1;
        $("#addserv").click(function(){
       
        $(".container").append("<div class='input-group mb-3' id='input-group' >\
                        <select class='form-control col-md-5 mr-2' name='' id='service1'>\
                        @foreach ($services as $s)\
                        <option id='option' data-index='{{$loop->index}}' value='{{$s -> servicePrice}}' >{{$s -> serviceName}}</option>\
                        @endforeach\
                        </select>\
                        <input type='number' class='form-control col-md-3 mr-2'  name='quantity'  id='weightsize" + j + "'data-index='" + j + "' >\
                        <input type='number' class='form-control col-md-3 mr-2' name='addonqty'  id='quantity" + j + "'data-index='" + j + "' >\
                        <button type='button' class='minus btn btn-danger' id='remove'><i class='fas fa-minus-circle'></i></button>\
                        " );
                        j++;
                        
        });

         //remove line
        $("body").on("click", ".minus", function() {
               $(this).closest("div").remove();
       });

       //calculation
       $('select, input[type=number], input[type=number]').each(function(){
            $(this).change(function(){
                calculateTotal();
            });
            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateTotal();
            });
        })

        function calculateTotal(){
            var total = 0;
            var selects = $("select#service1 option:checked");
                selects.each(function(){
                var currentWeightSize = $('#weightsize').val();
                var currentQuantity = $('#quantity').val();
                console.log(selects);
                console.log(currentWeightSize);
                console.log(currentQuantity);
                if(currentWeightSize != '' && currentWeightSize != undefined){
                    total += (parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat(currentWeightSize) * parseFloat(currentQuantity) );
                     console.log(total);
                }
            });
            $('#total').val(total);
        }
    });
    </script>

@endsection

                ```
````